# in graphql react do to 'loading' worked each time updated 'data'?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

in graphql do to 'loading' worked each time updated 'data'?

Now when first time loading true and when the next time he is always false although the data changes

```
const {loading, error, data, refetch, called } = useQuery(GET_COOKIES, {

    context: {
      headers: {"x-request-shop-id": props.currentStore ? props.currentStore.id : ""}},
    skip: !props.currentStore.id
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states):

> useQuery hook's result object provides fine-grained information about the status of the query via the `networkStatus` property. To take advantage of this information, we need to set the notifyOnNetworkStatusChange option to true so our query component re-renders while a refetch is in flight

```
const {loading, error, data, refetch, called, networkStatus } = useQuery(GET_COOKIES, {

    context: {
      headers: {"x-request-shop-id": props.currentStore ? props.currentStore.id : ""}},
    skip: !props.currentStore.id,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });

  if (networkStatus === 4) return 'Refetching!';
```

You can find all values in [source](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-client/src/core/networkStatus.ts)